# How can I auto select items in a multiselect listbox related to values in a table?

Tags: ms-access

So far I have accomplished the opposite of this - I have entered records into a table based on selections made in the multiselect listbox. The multiselect listbox was named "lstboxColor" and the table was named tblColors. This was accomplished with the following code:

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim itm As Variant
    cnnLocal.CursorLocation = adUseClient 'avoid error 3705

'SET UP A LOOP TO ADD A COLOR RECORD IN THE COLORS TABLE FOR EACH SELECTED COLOR
    rs.Open "tblColors", cnnLocal, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

   For Each itm In lstboxColor.ItemsSelected

        rs.AddNew
        rs!CrayonID = CrayonID_HOLD 
        rs!ColorID = lstboxColor.ItemData(itm)
        rs.Update

  Next

     rs.Close
```

So, now I would like to do the reverse of this - I need to open a form with a listbox and have the items in the multiselect listbox automatically be pre-selected based on the values in the table. Just can't seem to figure out the method needed other than looping through the table and using an if statement and .Selected = true. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Added current code that is almost working. Changed what I need to do - I am using 3 tables and having a combobox selection auto select rows in the listbox. The code is going in the combobox's AfterUpdate(). I added "Else: If rs.NoMatch Then .Selected(i) = False" - but that's not the problem. Thinking it may be the SQL query, but that same query pulls up the correct answer in a Subform, so I know the query works. Could it be the query that I am using for the listbox rows (which is only selecting EquipmentID and Equipment name from tblEquipment)? Please let me know what you think about the reason why it may only be highlighting one row in the listbox.

EDIT: This code is working for 3 tables. The selection in the combobox auto selects the correct rows in the listbox. Solution is marked for the 2 table version(or one table), but same concept.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Integer
Dim strSQL As String
Set db = CurrentDb

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblMusicEquipment.EquipmentID, * 
FROM tblMusic 
INNER JOIN (tblEquipment INNER JOIN tblMusicEquipment
ON tblEquipment.EquipmentID = tblMusicEquipment.EquipmentID)
ON tblMusic.InstrumentID = tblMusicEquipment.InstrumentID
WHERE  (((tblMusic.InstrumentID))) = " & [cboSelectInstrument])

With Me.LstEditEquip

    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1

       rs.FindFirst "EquipmentID =" & .ItemData(i)
       If Not rs.NoMatch Then
        .Selected(i) = True
       Else: If rs.NoMatch Then .Selected(i) = False
       End If

    Next

End With
```

Comment: Should use line continuation in code to make it more readable. Would be nice to provide sample of data as tables in question. Original example was about colors and only involved 2 tables. Specifics of issue have changed.

Comment: Your query pulls EquipmentID yet code indicates InstrumentID is value searched for. Are these really same thing? FindFirst syntax is not correct: `rs.FindFirst "EquipmentID=" & .ItemData(i)`

Comment: You nailed it. It was a combination of searching for the wrong thing and the syntax. It now works! Marking your question as the solution. Much thanks!

Comment: Marked your *ANSWER as the solution, Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to loop through listbox and compare to a value to determine selection. In your case, do a FindFirst on recordset. If match found then select item. Assuming value to match is a numeric key, consider:

```
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, i As Integer
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ColorID FROM tblColors WHERE CrayonID_HOLD=" & Me.CrayonID_HOLD)
    With Me.lstboxColor
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        rs.FindFirst "ColorID = " & .ItemData(i)
        .Selected(i) = Not rs.NoMatch
    Next
    End With
```

Comment: Haven't got it working yet...Do you know if this can work with ADODB? I noticed the FIndFirst and NoMatch properties are not available with ADODB. This DB currently uses ADODB recordsets and connections. Is it bad to mix DAO in the same project? If it's ok- do I need to set up a connection like ```Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
'Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
'Set cnnLocal = CurrentProject.Connection``` but with DAO??? Sorry, I'm only familiar so far with ADO... Thanks for the help. Will get this working soon!

Comment: UPDATE: Hi again June7, I got this almost working using the code you provided, but it is only selecting 1 row, no matter what. There are only 6 rows in the listbox. The number of the row it is selecting in the listbox corresponds to the ID number that is being passed to match. e.g. if ID '2' is passed then only row 2 in the listbox is selected, when in reality (to match with the table) it should be rows 1,2,4,5. Any ideas?

Comment: Code as posted (except using my db object names) works for me. It's not relevant that ID number matches row number - ID's could be 217, etc. It is an odd failure and I cannot explain it. Have you step debugged? Edit question to supply sample of data and your exact code. I have a slight edit to my code.

Comment: Added current exact code. 3 tables being used - Music, Equipment, MusicEquipment(links the other 2).